# How to extract IP address from the string

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to extract from the IP address from the string

```
import re
stri_ = '''192.168.1.1,192.168.1.2/32,192.168.1.5-192.168.1.7,reject,
reject,192.168.1.1/32,reject
172.168.1.4-172.168.1.4,reject
'''
ip_addr_with_range = re.findall('([0-9+-reject]+)\,(reject)*',stri_)
ip_addr_without_range = re.findall('/([0-9\-reject]+)*',stri_)
for i in ip_addr_with_range :
      print (i[0])
```

My Out

```
192.168.1.1,192.168.1.2/32,192.168.1.5-192.168.1.7,reject,reject,192.168.1.1/32
172.168.1.4-172.168.1.4
```

Desired Out

```
 ip_addr_with_range
[192.168.1.1,192.168.1.2/32,192.168.1.5,192.168.1.7,192.168.1.1/32,172.168.1.4,172.168.1.4]


ip_addr_without_range
 [192.168.1.1,192.168.1.2,192.168.1.5,192.168.1.7,192.168.1.1,172.168.1.4,172.168.1.4]
```

Comment: 100% IPv4, only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work.

```
ip_addr_with_range = re.findall('\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\/?\d{0,}', stri_)
ip_addr_without_range = re.findall('\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}', stri_)
```

Comment: 999.999.999.999 is a valid IPv4 address ?